# Rails 5 production assets precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, yarnpkg

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server for deploying multiple RoR apps.
I'm using an Amazon EC2 machine with a Nginx webserver managing multiple RoR app on different domains. Some products are in development environment for testing and others in production environment.

I decided to update a site installing a HTTP certificate with certbot.
I followed the instructions below and everything was fine.

https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-nginx

After updating the production assets with:

```
`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`
```

I have the following message instead of the list of assets files generated
Installing certbot I broke some dependencies for assets compiling flow?

```
`Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install`
```

I tried to install yarn with `npm` globally but after I have:

```
`yarn install v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
info Lockfile not saved, no dependencies.
Done in 0.09s.`
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see, Yarn is a package. Please install that package via npm (on your production server):

`npm install yarn -g`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, I tried to install with nom and set yarn as globally (-g) but the result is my last snippet code.

Comment: could you run

`npm -v`

`yarn -v`

and

`yarn` ?

Comment: `npm -v: 5.6.0`
`node -v: 9.4.0`
`yarn -v: 1.3.2`

Comment: @andreapavan honestly, I faced this problem yesterday, right before you post this Q. And after 2 hours, do everything, it worked.

- cd to /home/../myfolder/

- run yarn

- cd out, and cd back to /home/../myfolder

- run `npm install yarn -g` again